# How can I Intercept a function in Node.js with Proxy and apply?

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I am wondering whether this is the right way to intercept an function in node. I this particular case I'd like to invoke some handler when the `use` function of express.js's router is called.

Here's the example code:

```js
const express = require('express');

const rootRouter = express.Router();

const useHandler = {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log('router was mounted');
  }
};

// This works, but I am not sure, whether it
// should be done this way:
rootRouter.use = new Proxy(router.use, useHandler);

const usersRouter = express.Router();

rootRouter.use(usersRouter);
```

I am not sure, whether it's ok to replace the old `use` function with its proxy version, in order to intercept it?

Or should it be done differently?

Comment: This is a technique called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). Obviously JavaScript is pretty accommodating of it...so you certainly can do it. You'll find opinions will vary widely as to whether you should do it. It's really about understanding the pros/cons, and hopefully getting buy-in from anyone else in your org or dev team that will be working with the code.

Comment: I am pretty aware of the downside of overwriting a function with another one and I am not 100% fond of it either.

Therefore I am asking: if that technique has "a smell" and I still need to intercept the function, what would be an "odour free" alternative?